# Highlighting strings with different orders in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to highlight the strings. Whether they are in the sequence or not.
Like this -

```
$str = "star 5 hotel";
$keywords = "5 star hotels";
```

There is my function. It only highlights the last matching string.Here `$str` contains the search string. `$keyword` contains that string which i have stored into database

How can i highlight each matching string.

```
    function highlight($str, $keyword) {
    
        $str = "star hotel 5";
        $keyword = "5 star hotel";
        
        foreach($look as $find){
            if(strpos($keyword, $find) !== false) {
                if(!isset($highlight)){ 
                    $highlight[] = $find;
                    
                } else { 
                    if(!in_array($find,$highlight)){ 
                        $highlight[] = $find;
                        
                    } 
                }
            }   
        } 

        

        if(isset($highlight)){ 
            foreach($highlight as $replace){
                $str = str_ireplace($replace,'<b>'.$replace.'</b>',$keyword);
                $stra[] = str_ireplace($replace,'<b>'.$replace.'</b>',$keyword);

                echo "<pre>";
                print_r ($stra);
                echo "</pre>";
            } 
        } 
        echo $str."<br>";
        die();
        return $str;

    }
```

But when i put this into an array and  when i print this array `$stra[]`. It given me this

Array
(

> [0] => 5 **star** hotel
>
> [1] => **5** star hotel
>
> [2] => 5 star **hotel**

)

I can not find way to combine these.

**Output :** -If have that keyword which is searching . then this must be Highlighted..

**5 star hotel**

Comment: What you want as o/p ?

Comment: Somthing like  **5 Star Hotel**

Comment: Wow the downvotes are like rain in the UK, everywhere. I'm not entering this storm.

Comment: Who ever down vote this question. They will have to mention a reason. i think.it May have helpful for me while questing..next time???

Comment: I don't know why it has been downvoted. In my opinion you have ticked all boxes of a good question. You have a description, input, expected output, code attempt. I don't know what is missing.

Comment: Maybe someone who got angry that you downvoted their answer?
If not, the only possible reason is that you haven't stated all of your requirements? String-size, amount of keywords, are duplicate keywords possible? Or because your sample code contains mistakes like the `die()` or reassigning the arguments?

Comment: @Benedikt Are you sure it's Vishal who downvote here?

Comment: @Benedikt  i have not given a single down vote down there.Here every answer has  given me  new ideas. I think i have now three ways to solve this. Now i totally confused to accept an answer..

Comment: @Andreas How could I be sure? Its just a assumption, no charge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is what I assumed:-***

*I assume that you want to search each word of the search sting in the given string and if and only if all the words found then make string in bold (complete string).*

***Then do like below (Explanation given in comments):-***

```
<?php

$search = "star 5 hotel"; //search string
$string = "5 star hotels"; // string in which you want to search

function highlight($search, $string) {

  $new_search = array_unique(array_filter(explode(" " ,$search)));//explode search string
  $found_count = 0; //create a counter
  foreach($new_search as $find){ // iterate over search words array
     if(strpos($string, $find) !== false) { // if word found in the string
        $found_count +=1; // increase the counter
     }
  }
  if(count($new_search) == $found_count){ //check that all words found in the string
     $string = "<b>". $string ."</b>"; // if yes then make each word of the string bold
  }

  return $string; //return the newly modified string
}

echo highlight($search, $string); // echo newly modified string
```

Output:- https://eval.in/838325

Comment: Your answer failes for strings like `"5 star luxury hotels"`. Luxury gets highlighted, too.

Comment: @BenediktMokroß  no.check once.

Comment: https://eval.in/838331 `in` and `luxury` are highlighted. But they are no keywords. And here the whole sentence is highlighted: https://eval.in/838332

Comment: @BenediktMokroß   did you checked my assumption?According to my assumption code worked fine.

Comment: Thing is, the asker didn't specify this behavior. So it's an answer for your assumption, not his question.

Comment: @BenediktMokroß  i just gave an answer, i din't force OP to mark my answer accepted. I just gave an answer with my assumption only.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array, and  `strtr()` function. :)

```
$str = "the quick brown fox";
$keywords = "quick fox brown";
$matches = explode(" ",$keywords);
foreach ($matches as $v) {
    $arr_matches[$v] = "<b>".$v."</b>";
}
$str = strtr($str, $arr_matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but here is one way to make a double loop that will keep the bloat tags to a minimum and handle extra words in the sentence (in what I think is correct way).

It checks if the word is in match list, if yes loop til there is a not matching word.
Add the tags around those two words and go back to main loop.

```
$str = "star 5 hotel";
$strarr =explode(" ", $str);
$keywords = "a 5 star uinique hotel";

$arr = explode(" ", $keywords);

For($i=0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++){
    If(in_array($arr[$i], $strarr)){
        $j=$i;
        While(in_array($arr[$j], $strarr) && $j < count($arr)){
           $j++;
        }
        $j--;
        $arr[$i] = "<b>" . $arr[$i];
        $arr[$j] = $arr[$j] . "</b>";
        $i=$j;
    }
}

Echo implode(" ", $arr);
```

Output of above example:

```
a <b>5 star</b> uinique <b>hotel</b>
```

https://3v4l.org/pKE4X

Comment: I wish i could accept more than two or three answers. Now I got four ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just iterate over your keywords and replace them:

```
$str = "This is a star 5 hotel located in New York";
$keywords = array("5","star","hotels");
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value){
    $str = str_replace($value, "<b>".$value."</b>", $str);
}
```

Simple and failsafe if you don't have double keywords.

---

Or if your keywords need to be a **something-separated string**:

```
$str = "This is a star 5 hotel located in New York";
$keywords = "5 star hotel";
$arraykeywords = explode(" ",$keywords); 
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value){
    $str = str_replace($value, "<b>".$value."</b>", $str);
}
```

---

To **filter double keywords** use `array_unique`:

```
$str = "This is a star 5 hotel located in New York";
$keywords = "5 star hotel star";
$arraykeywords = array_unique(explode(" ",$keywords)); 
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value){
    $str = str_replace($value, "<b>".$value."</b>", $str);
}
```

---

After a lot of discussion about regex (see the comments), this is the approach using @Andreas's regex:

```
$str = "This is a star 5 hotel located in New York";
$keywords = "5 star hotel star";
$pregsearch = "/".implode("|",array_unique(explode(" ",$keywords)))."/g"; //remove dups and join as regex
$str = preg_replace($pregsearch, "<b>$0</b>", $str);
```

Only recomended if your searching a large string.

Comment: I have that multiple keywords with the same name

Comment: I saw there was a comment here about not using regex because it's slow. I actually think in this case regex will be faster than looping each word. Of course it depends on the size of sentence. But I wouldn't rule out regex from this question. I'm usually against using regex for everything but in this case I actually think it's a good tool.

Comment: @Andreas Could not agree more on that. Thats why I mentioned regex in the first place. Its a simple task for like it seems to be small strings. So regex would be fine. Another plus: It wont bloat your code. (Not using regex in _php_ because of performance concerns? c'mon...)

Comment: Performance concerns are actually a good reason in my opinion. If you look at some regex answers here they are just a substitute for a normal php function (for real I have seen this: `/.{11}/` as an answer). In those case it's probably two or three times as slow as normal php. However with exploding and looping it adds up. So a three word sentence may be about the same or slightly faster than regex. But as the length of sentence grows I thing regex will be faster and faster.

Comment: @Andreas well, I've not thought of using regex for basically everything. Under your stated circumstances you are very right. Also: I've skipped the regex-approach because it looks like we will work with very small data, thus the regex would be too much overhead.

Comment: Here is a regex that will do the job. But it will "bloat" with unnecessary tags. https://regex101.com/r/HSK6Xu/2 if you don't want the bloat tags you have to loop. One loop that checks first if it matches, then another who loops inside until end of match.

Comment: I did not mean you use regex to everything. But there are some here who use regex as soon as they can it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to achieve:

```
$str      = 'This is some 5 start hotel in US';
$keyWords = ['5', 'star', 'hotel'];

$strToCheck = explode(' ', $str);

foreach ($keyWords as $k => $v)
{
    if (in_array($v, $strToCheck)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

this creates the string as an array, this means we can use `in_array` to check, then inside the if statement do whatever :)

references:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php